# ROS GUI for Android

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, qtcreator, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone developed a ROS GUI for android devices?
I want to make a GUI to control a mobile robot depending on ROS packages through android devices. I think I should send ROS messages via WIFI network.

I found that some people used QT Creator but there wasn't any clear document.

Does anyone have any advices?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351195/ros-gui-for-android/) by [tungngo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33618/tungngo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2020-05-01

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yep, check out:
https://github.com/ROS-Mobile/ROS-Mobile-Android

Maybe this will help you a little to get started.

---

Originally posted by [Schneewittchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/51156/schneewittchen/) with karma: 51 on 2021-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2